# Good jquery datagrid that works well with .net (2.0) services

Tags: jquery, datagrid

I'm trying to find a jquery datagrid which has the following:

- Allows to use the scroll bar to fetch the next page of data.
- Is able to handle high volume of data.
- Works with .NET (2.0) services

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend to load a lot of rows on the same page. It will slow down the page.

I don't recommend you to use the scrollbar to load new rows. There will always be a delay and 
several ajax requests will be invoked if the user continues to scroll the bar (and by doing so put load on your server/db).

I've created a grid which can use a "show more" button to load more rows in the table or use a traditional page pager.

It's easy to create custom filtering to let the user to quickly find the wanted rows (It's much better from a users perspective to search/filter than load a large number of rows).

https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.table

Comment: I'm stuck in .net 2.0, I see that your solution is using 3.5. You have an alternate solution?

Comment: HiteshRana: it should work with .NET services as long as they can return JSON. The actual JSON format is documented in the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this option

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx